# Validating more than one message returned from the actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

An akka-testkit question.

Could some one advise on how do I validate that actor 'A' when received message x, has responded with two messages  - y and z.

Messages x,y,z are all of different types.

I don't see any suitable 'expect*' function that would support such tests.

p.s
Code examples in Scala please.
Thanks.

Comment: You could provide a code snippet of what you already tried

Comment: class A extends Actor {
   def receive {
     case x:X => 
        <do something ..>
        sender ! Y()
        sender ! Z()
    ....
  }
}
I'm using the ImplicitSender trait mixed into my test class, in order to catch all returned messages.
I can see that 
`expectMsgAllOf[T](d: Duration, obj: T*): Seq[T]` or  `expectMsgAllClassOf[T](d: Duration, c: Class[_ <: T]*): Seq[T]`
are expecting messages of the same type or super type, but in my case the types of messages which are returned from actor A are different.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use the
`expectMsgAllClassOf[T](d: Duration, c: Class[_ <: T]*): Seq[T]`.
Full example:

```
case class X(i:Int)  
case class Y(i:Int)  
case class Z(i:Int)

class UnderTest extends Actor {  
 def receive {  
   case x:X =>
     sender ! Y(1)
     sender ! Z(1)
  }
}  

class MyTest extends AkkaTestKit with ImplicitSender {  

val beingTested = system.actorOf(Props[UnderTest])
beingTested ! X(1)

val receivedMsgs = expectedMsgAllClassOf(classOf[Y],classOf[Z])

// Your received messages are in the receivedMsgs sequence first is Y //second is Z
//you can extract them and validating the exact result with assertions  
}
```